# sort php array by extracting time from html within

Tags: php, html, arrays, sorting

I have an array that has some html in it as values. In that html are dates. I'd like to sort the array by those dates.

Array looks like:

```
Array(
    [0] => '<div class="date">April 6, 2016</div>'
    [1] => '<div class="date">January 23, 2016</div>'
    [2] => '<div class="date">March 6, 2016</div>'
    [3] => '<div class="date">December 5, 2016</div>'
)
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
Array(
    [0] => '<div class="date">January 23, 2016</div>'
    [1] => '<div class="date">March 6, 2016</div>'
    [2] => '<div class="date">April 6, 2016</div>'
    [3] => '<div class="date">December 5, 2016</div>'
)
```

Just using `sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC)` or `rsort()`, doesn't work. My guess is that I need to use `usort()` and then create a function that will compare stripped array values (only dates). But I don't know how to start.

Any help is welcome.

**EDIT**

I started working on a function:

```
function strip_sort_array($a){
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        $date = substr($value, 18, 32);
    }
}
```

This returns the date. This can be converted to unix with strtotime. I just need to use this for comparison somehow...

Comment: You need some string manipulation strtotime with some regex or substr

Comment: In your function, you'll probably use strip_tags() & strtotime() to get numeric values that you can sort.

Comment: I edited the question. I can get the date, I just don't know how to use this to sort my array :\

Comment: You don't need that function because PHP has one built in. Yes, you can convert to a timestamp with `strtotime()`. You already mentioned that you know about `usort()`. So use it. If you have specific problems doing that, ask for more specific help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, most of this answer already exists at http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

So I don't feel too bad just giving teh codez here.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b76d5119fe1aeb269d38db5ce266306e36e7c58

OP, become familiar with php.net and you'll be able to figure these things out on your own.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
  $a=strtotime(strip_tags($a));
  $b=strtotime(strip_tags($b));
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
$date[]='<div class="date">April 6, 2016</div>';
$date[]='<div class="date">January 23, 2016</div>';
$date[]='<div class="date">March 6, 2016</div>';
$date[]='<div class="date">December 5, 2016</div>';

usort($date, "cmp");

var_export($date);
```

Comment: My original array is a bit more complex, but I'll make use of this. Thanks.

Comment: I like this answer, fancy.

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert your time to a timestamp.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php

Then create a new array, use the timestamp as key and the html as value. Then sort by key.

Comment: I don't want to write the correct function for you, I have answered your question based on your edits.

Comment: Downvoters, please take the time to write a comment to let me know your thoughts. I want to improve my answers, even they are not the chosen answer by op. My answer is just a hint how to achieve the wanted result by using the timestamps as array keys while creating the array in the first place, this would reduce the sort part to one line with the php ksort function.